# python - print last matching line in file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm reading various logs from a Windows Server and current am grabbing the most recent log in a folder.

I then want to scan that log and only print the last line where it contains a particular string.

The following will print all lines containing the string -

```
def read_logfile(master_log):
    for line in master_log:
        if line.contains('[76:Health]:'):
            print line
```

How do I get it to print only the last match that it's found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way to do this is just store every time you get a hit, and print outside the loop:

```
def read_logfile(master_log):
    lastmatch = None
    for line in master_log:
        if '[76:Health]:' in line:
            lastmatch = line
    if lastmatch is not None:
        print lastmatch
```

You can generalize to the last `n` matches using a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with an appropriate `maxlen`, so you just `append` all matches as you go, pushing out the oldest once you exceed the limit. The following works identically to the code above, but allows a second argument that prints more lines:

```
from collections import deque

def read_logfile(master_log, linecount=1):
    lastmatches = deque(maxlen=linecount)
    for line in master_log:
        if '[76:Health]:' in line:
            lastmatches.append(line)
    for line in lastmatches:
        print line
```

Comment: The first option works perfectly I should have realized though that python does not have a string.contains() I actually had to do `if '[76:Health]:' in line:`

Comment: @whoisearth: Oops, I should have caught that myself. :-) I'll fix in the answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over your file in reversed order.

```
for line in reversed(master_log.readlines()):
    if '[76:Health]:' in line:
        print(line)
        break
```

If your file is small, reading it in won't be a problem. If it is large, choose another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in an array and then print the last item in the array. Can use `pop` to return the line as a `str`.

```
 def read_logfile(master_log):
        last_line_holder = []
        for line in master_log:
            if line.contains('[76:Health]:'):
                last_line_holder.append(line)
        print(last_line_holder[-1])
```